# Pry not stopping when called from a Ruby script that reads from stdin

Tags: ruby, pry

I've created a console Ruby script that uses ARGF to load data from a file or stdin, that then calls Pry.

This works great when I pass a file in (Pry pauses) but fails (Pry doesn't stop and just exits Ruby) when I pass my data using stdin.

This is weird, anyone know why? I would like to pass data in via stdin and have Pry pause.

Behold, an example script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pry'


def pry_it(str)
    binding.pry
end

pry_it(ARGF.read)
```

When I call this app with a file in ARGV I get my proper response - pry pausing

```
% bundle exec ruby pry_test.rb file.txt

From: /Users/wilcoxr/Development/json_pry/pry_test.rb @ line 8 Object#pry_it:

    6: def pry_it(str)
    7:
 => 8:  binding.pry
    9: end

[1] pry(main)>
```

Great! I can execute Pry commands all I want

When I try to use STDIN to send data into my tool:

```
% cat file.txt | bundle exec ruby pry_test.rb

From: /Users/wilcoxr/Development/json_pry/pry_test.rb @ line 8 Object#pry_it:

    6: def pry_it(str)
    7:
 => 8:  binding.pry
    9: end

[1] pry(main)>
%
```

Look closely: note I'm back at my shell prompt, not pauses in IRB. Weird! I don't understand why I'm getting this behavior....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `ARGF` with simple:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pry'
binding.pry
```

Now `IO` operations are not covered internally by `ARGF.read` and it became evident what’s wrong here. `ARGF` is “glued” to `STDIN`, therefore whatever is being passed to `STDIN` goes directly to `pry`’s input.

I do not know exactly, what instruction in your `file.txt` forces pry to quit, but there is one.

---

**UPDATE**

It looks like *if a Ruby script yields anything on `stdin`* (e. g. through a pipe,) both `$stdin` and `STDIN` are set to this pipe, messing up `pry`’s “where am I run from” detection.

I came up with this not-so-elegant solution:

```
# read input from ARGF
text = ARGF.read

# prepare new stdin to satisfy pry
pry_fd_stdin = IO.sysopen("/dev/tty")
pry_stdin = IO.new(pry_fd_stdin, "r")

# load pry and cheat it with our stdio
require 'pry'
Pry.config.input = pry_stdin

binding.pry
```

This solution has some glitches (e.g. pry prompt is shown only *after* input).

Comment: I suspect you're on to something. I don't think it's the contents of my input file that causes Pry to do things... but I agree with you that STDIN may be interacting with PRY in fun ways


Because here's another example of what's up: `echo "hi" | bundle exec ruby pry_test.rb`.

This gives the same result as above: a quick exit

Comment: Try to run the code above with `ruby pry_test.rb < file.txt`, you’ll see what’s happening in details. It appears that `pry` throws an error and [likely] continues it’s execution, leading your script to exit.

Comment: Ok, yes I agree. I also checked the TTY status of stdin (with `puts IO.pipe.map(&:tty?)`), and it returns false. So I guess Pry reads from STDIN, either reading commands from stdin OR seeing that we're at the end of STDIN - because we read it all, like my example does - AND that we're not an interactive terminal, and exits. So ummm... how do I get around that I wonder...

Comment: Thank you - this works to some extent, as you mentioned - but a painful glitch I am experiencing is the total absence of the command-line capabilities typically provided by the `readline` library: **moving on the `pry` command-line** (e.g. moving back a character is not possible), and **reverse-searching `pry` history** (i.e. hitting `control-r` to search the history of previously entered `pry` commands is not possible). Might you know of any workaround for this issue?