# Is it possible to launch a Ruby debugger from within the Logstash Ruby filter plugin?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

Is it possible to launch a Ruby debugger from within the [Logstash Ruby filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html)?  It would be very handy for debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The good Logstash folks have thought of this already as they included [`pry`](http://pryrepl.org/) into Logstash core. So all you have to do is to require pry in your `ruby` filter code as shown in the sample config below:

```
input { 
  file {
    path => "/tmp/myfile.csv"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
filter {
  ruby {
    code => "require 'pry'
       ... your code ...

       # start a REPL session
       binding.pry

       ... your code ...
    "
 }
}
```

When Logstash runs, you'll get a REPL session in your terminal which looks like this and you'll be able to do whatever pry allows you to do.

```
[1] pry(#<LogStash::Filters::Ruby>)>
```

Comment: I can see it trying to launch the pry session, but it just doesn't break.. It just keeps going and doesn't give me the chance to enter the debug session.  I think it might be due to the fact that I'm using stdin as my input plugin, and I pipe my CSV file into logstash.

Comment: In my test I did use the stdin input as well and it worked. Can you show your logstash config ?

Comment: simplified because of client work:

`input { stdin { } }

filter {
   csv {
        columns => ["field1", "field2"]
        separator => ","
   }

   ruby {
    init => "
      require 'pry'
    "

    code => "
      binding.pry
    "
}
`

Comment: and then I start it with:

$ ESENV=development /usr/local/bin/logstash-2.3.4/bin/logstash -v --allow-env -f import.conf < /tmp/myfile.csv

Comment: can you try to require pry in the code part and not the init part?

Comment: `Pipeline main started
[1] pry(#<LogStash::Filters::Ruby>)> CSVROW1,CSVROW2,etc,
SyntaxError: unexpected ','`

but it keeps going for every row in the CSV file.

Comment: Let me try your setup locally and get back to you.

Comment: The issue seems to be related to [reading from stdin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32333962/pry-not-stopping-when-called-from-a-ruby-script-that-reads-from-stdin). Instead, if you use a `file` input, you'll get your REPL session as expected. I've updated my answer. Try it out.