# pry does not drop into REPL at breakpoint

Tags: ruby, pry

Pry does not drop me into its REPL at the breakpoint in the following function.

```
def print_lines(data)
  puts "here's the input I got:"

  data.each_with_index do |line, index|
    url_regex = /(?:<a href=")(https?:\/{2}www.\w+[.](com|org|net)((\/\w+)*([.]\w+)?))(?:">)/

    binding.pry

    url = line.scan(url_regex)[0]

    puts "Line #{index}: #{url}"

  end

end
```

Instead, it produces the following output:

```
From: /Users/hsb/work/hr-solutions/detect-html-links/lib/script.rb @ line 13 Object#print_lines:

4: def print_lines(data)
...
=> 13:     url = line.scan(url_regex)[0]
...
19: end
(END)
```

When I type `q`, pry display the same output for each remaining iteration of the loop. Any idea why I'm not getting access to the REPL to investigate variables in the scope?

Comment: I was using STDIN to read in data. There seems to be some problem with pry and STDIN. Reading here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32333962/pry-not-stopping-when-called-from-a-ruby-script-that-reads-from-stdin

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this issue with STDIN are well documented! This solution worked for me: http://rocket-science.ru/hacking/2015/09/02/pry-and-stdin

Comment: This is not about “pry’s problems,” this is about pry’s smart enough to understand that standard input is now not something it can use for interactive operation.